# Getting the opened BS Panel to the top of the page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a panel made with bootstrap 3 that appears around the bottom of the page because of the content above it. When I open it, it slides its content below the page view. How can I get it to position itself to the top of the page after it has been opened (assuming there is enough content inside of it or below it to position itself there)?

Here is what I tried...

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n2fole00/w802s6t4/

```
$('a[href="#daily-accordion"]').click(function(event){

    $(document).scrollTop($('#daily-accordion-group').offset().top);

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by top of the page? Please explain it a little briefly.

Comment: Perhaps top of the viewport would be more accurate. It's like the user opens the panel and then scrolls so that the panel a:link appears at the top of the user's view with the body of the panel filling as much of the page as possible. This is the state I would like the panel to open in.

Comment: No elements are swapped or moved around in the process. I see how the question could have been interpreted like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more digging (I did spend hours before-hand), this worked...

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#daily-accordion-group').offset().top}, 'slow');
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/n2fole00/w802s6t4/4/